# Firebase onAuthStateChange() not working, still being redirected to login page on refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi there I'm still new to ReactJS and I've just started using Firebase, where I'm currently following along a tutorial; The issue that I'm facing is that every time I refresh the page I'm thrown back to my sign in page, I've also created protected routes to check whether the user is logged in or not but this wouldn't be the case, as I've been shuffling the onAuthStateChange() around to see whether it's not firing before hand, but I'm still stuck in the rabbit hole.

***"Take note I am using firebase v9"***

#### My userAuth() context

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from '../config/firebase';
import {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    signOut,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    confirmPasswordReset,
    sendPasswordResetEmail,
    GoogleAuthProvider,
    signInWithPopup
} from 'firebase/auth';

const userAuthContext = createContext();

export function UserAuthContextProvider({children}){
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    function signUp(email, password){
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }

    function signIn(email, password){
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }

    function googleSignIn(){
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        return signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    }

    function logOut(){
        return signOut(auth);
    }

    function forgotPassword(email){
        return sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email, {url:'http://localhost:3000/signin'});
    }

    function resetPassword(oobCode, newPassword){
        return confirmPasswordReset(auth, oobCode, newPassword);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
            setUser(currentUser);
        })

        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        }
    },[]);

    return (
        <userAuthContext.Provider value={{
            user, 
            signIn, 
            googleSignIn, 
            signUp, 
            logOut, 
            forgotPassword,
            resetPassword}}
        >
            {children}
        </userAuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export function UserAuth(){
    return useContext(userAuthContext);
}
```

#### My Protected Route

```
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserAuth } from "../../context/userAuth";

const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  const {user} = UserAuth();
  
  return (
    <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => 
        user ? (
          <Component {...props}/>
        ):(
          <Redirect to="/signin"/>
        ) 
      }
    />
  )
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

#### I've wrapped the UserAuthContextProvider in index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <UserAuthContextProvider>
    <App />
  </UserAuthContextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: although I haven't used react before but I have done this in Vue.. I believe whats happening is you are rending before the async result which check whether user is logged in or not. I suggest that you add loading to the main view.. check for auth (again which is async request) and if successful, direct user to the route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal, when you refreshed the page you lost the state of the app. Use `localstorage` to store `user`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe;
    const user = localStorage.getItem('user'); // <=== save the state in localStorage

    if (user) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(user));
    } else {
      unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
        setUser(currentUser);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      });
    }
 
    return () => {
      if(unsubscribe) unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I don't understand why I'm still getting the user as null which is then taking me back to signin, could it be that my UserAuthContextProvider is wrapped incorrectly not giving it time to perform the check, apologies I'm lost with this issue.

Comment: This worked, I changed the private route as well by making use of the localStorage like you've mentioned and its working perfectly fine now. Thanks.

Comment: According to the Firebase docs, this added step of interacting with local storage should not be necessary.

With this approach, you'll be able to route your client locally, but he will not be authenticated. When you try to query Firebase, it should fail.